# Azure web site not recognizing perfectly valid CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system, azure

I'm trying to add a custom domain to an Azure Web Site in standard mode. I've added the following DNS records:

```
@                     IN  A       168.62.48.183
www                   IN  CNAME   ua-roadtosochi.azurewebsites.net.
awverify              IN  CNAME   awverify.ua-roadtosochi.azurewebsites.net.
awverify.www          IN  CNAME   awverify.ua-roadtosochi.azurewebsites.net.
```

Azure keeps telling me that it cannot find my CNAME record. It has been several hours since I made this change. Is azure's internal DNS caching really that slow, or have I made a typo somewhere that I'm not seeing?

Edit: Several hours later, still no dice. This has got to be an issue with azure websites, no? I can't figure out what the hell is wrong.

Comment: Can you do the lookup yourself?  Typos and caching are not the only two possibilities.

Comment: Yes, I can do the lookup just fine. It appears to resolve fine in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to add the domain today. Apparently it really was just a cached records issue.

Comment: DNS is cached in many places and it can take several hours to replicate. I've seen this take anything from 5-10 minutes to a day.

Comment: Yeah I'm well aware of that. I usually give it 24 ~hours. This one too almost 3 full days to replicate, however.